# Unable to click the element which is visible after filling up the source box

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

When I fill the source text box and then try to select the options on the basis of searching the particular item, I'm unable to select the item. This is my code

```
driver.get("http://bus.easemytrip.com/");
WebElement src=driver.findElement(By.id("txtSrcCity"));
src.click();
src.sendKeys("agra");
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Agra']")).click();
```

```html
<div class="bus-from">
<label>From :</label>
<input id="txtSrcCity" class="select-txtn-bus ng-untouched ng-not-empty ng-dirty ng-valid-parse ng-valid ng-valid-required" type="text" placeholder="Source City" name="txtSrcCity" ng-model="search.source" autocomplete="off" ng-change="OnSourceEdit()" required=""/>
<div class="drop" ng-show="sourceDiv">
<ul>
<!-- ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra 1 Day Package</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra 1 Day Tour</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra Fort</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Jaipur Agra Mathura Tour</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Jaipur Ajmer Agra Tour</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra Cantt Railway Station</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agra I.s.b.t</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
<li class="ng-binding ng-scope" ng-click="SetSource(src.id,src.name)" ng-repeat="src in sourceCity">Agrahar</li>
<!-- end ngRepeat: src in sourceCity -->
</ul>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It takes some time for the dropdown to appear. You can use `explicit wait` with [Expected Conditions](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/support/ui/ExpectedConditions.html) to wait for it to be visible

```
driver.get("http://bus.easemytrip.com/");
WebElement src=driver.findElement(By.id("txtSrcCity"));
src.click();
src.sendKeys("agra");

WebDriverWait wait = new WebDriverWait(driver, 10);
WebElement option = wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//li[text()='Agra']")));
option.click();
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you're going to be able to locate an item with the code as you have it:

```
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//li[text()='Agra']")).click();
```

Because you are searching for a list item whose text EQUALS 'Agra' and the keys you sent to the textbox was 'agra'.  After sending 'agra' to the textbox, the result option list is probably empty.